# How to avoid 'Trying to get property of non-object in' notice

Tags: php

I am trying to download multi-line orders from eBay in a loop. If it is not a multi line order, which is most orders, I get:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in....line 605

Here is my code:

```
for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= $n_ord; $counter += 1) {
    $multi=0;
    if (!is_object($retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]->TransactionArray->Transaction[$multi]->OrderLineItemID)) {    
        $OrderLinetest = '';
    } else {
        $OrderLinetest = $retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]->TransactionArray->Transaction[$multi]->OrderLineItemID;
    }
    while ($OrderLinetest<>''){
        //:
        //Process the order
        //:
        $multi++;               //line 604:
        if (!is_object($retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]->TransactionArray->Transaction[$multi]->OrderLineItemID)) {    
            $OrderLinetest = '';    //line 605:  
        } else {
            $OrderLinetest = $retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]->TransactionArray->Transaction[$multi]->OrderLineItemID;
        }
    } // end multi item while loop 
} // end for loop of items
```

What is the best way to test if it is an object?

Should I use `isset`?

Comment: need context, more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP actually has a function built in called [is_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) for determining whether something is an object, which you're already using.

Your problem is that you're checking if this is an object:

```
$retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]->TransactionArray->Transaction[$multi]->OrderLineItemID
```

But, what if one of the following is not set?

- `$retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]->TransactionArray->Transaction[$multi]`
- `$retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]->TransactionArray`
- `$retxml->OrderArray[0]->Order[$counter]`
- `$retxml->OrderArray[0]`
- `$retxml`

Unfortunately, you have many levels fof data, and are only checking on the deepest.

As per your original question, pertaining to using `isset` - the answer is likely yes, you should use it in order to determine what you need. Be aware of the differences between `isset` and `empty` in determining whether something is a valid value too.

Have you attempted to wrap the code with an `isset`? What result did you get, and did it satisfy your needs?

Comment: I am using  is_object on line 605 hence the question on stackoverflow...
Am i using it incorrectly?

Comment: If it does not return an object, I want to exit the loop.